# GraphQL: Only fetch objects with a certain property equals `null`

Tags: filter, graphql

I have a GraphQL query

```
query testQuery {
  books {
    title
    isbn
    publisher
    metadata {
      propertyA
      propertyB
      propertyC
    }
  }
}
```

In the GraphQL schema, `metadata` is an optional field. The other three are required, and all of them are string.

My question: I only want to filter items where the `metadata` **is** null or empty. I use GraphiQL.

For a string I can use `where: {someString: {_isNull: true}}`, but for a nested object this is not possible.

Comment: Okay I can answer my own question: `books(where: {_not: {metadata: {}}})` will do the job.